# Como mudar o delay do setInterval programaticamente?

Tags: javascript

Tentei desta forma mas não obtive sucesso. Minha intenção é fazer como um efeito da curva de Bézier.

```js
var count = 0;

var times = 100;
var fn = function() {
  count++;
  
  if(count === 25) {
    console.log(count, times);
    times = 1000;
  }
  if(count === 50) {
    console.log(count, times);
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  
  document.getElementById('div').style.left = count + 'px';
}

var interval = setInterval(fn, times);
```

```css
#div {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma vez começado o `setInterval` consome os argumentos que lhe foram passados e já não volta a verifica-los.

Sugiro que uses o `setTimeout` pois assim ele vai ter de ser chamado novamente a cada vez que um `times` expirar.

```js
var count = 0;

var times = 100;
function periodical() {
  count++;
  
  if(count === 25) {
    console.log(count, times);
    times = 1000;
  }
  if(count === 50) {
    console.log(count, times);
    return;
  }
  
  document.getElementById('div').style.left = count + 'px';
  setTimeout(periodical, times);
}

setTimeout(periodical(), times);
```

```css
#div {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do Sergio atende plenamente ao processo desejado. Entretando, para fins de esclarecimento para outros usuários com uma dúvida que corresponda plenamente ao título da questão -

Mantenha uma **referência** ao *scheduler*:

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000); // Um segundo (1000 ms) de intervalo
```

Quando desejar mudar a frequência, elimine o *scheduler* via **`clearInterval()`**:

```
clearInterval(myVar);
```

Associe um **novo** *scheduler* à referência:

```
myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 3000); // três segundos de intervalo
```